# cash denomination calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created cash denomination calculator in jquery, and it's working fine once you add entry but suppose if you try to change those entries then it's not calculating values as i expected.

Just fill those values and you'll get total of all, but if try to change the value of input box inside div with '.mul_by' class[i.e. the small input box before '=' sign] then it's not calculating the total properly.

And here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kishan93/nkdagkm2/1/) for the same.

```js
$('.mul_by').each(function (i) {
    var _this = $(this),
        //set default input value to zero inside .mul-by div
        setZero = _this.find('.form-control').val(0),
        //set default input value to zero inside .mul-val div
        setDenominationVal = _this.siblings('.mul_val').find('.form-control').val(0),

        //set default input value to zero inside .total div
        setTotalVal = $('.total').val(0);
    setZero.on('change', function () {
        //watch and store input val. inside .mul_by
        var getUpdatedVal = _this.find('.form-control').val(),
            //get label text
            getDenominationVal = parseInt(_this.siblings('label').text()),
            //update mul_by div after multiplication
            updateDenominationVal = _this.siblings('.mul_val').find('.form-control');

        if (getUpdatedVal > 0) {
            var vals = updateDenominationVal.val(getUpdatedVal * getDenominationVal);
            total = parseInt(setTotalVal.val()) + parseInt(vals.val());
            setTotalVal.val(total);
        } else {
            updateDenominationVal.val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-2" for="batch">2000</label>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 mul_by">
            <span>x </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 mul_val">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;">= </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-2" for="batch">500</label>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 mul_by">
            <span>x </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 mul_val">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;">= </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-2" for="batch">100</label>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 mul_by">
            <span>x </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 mul_val">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;">= </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <hr>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-2" for="batch">total:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 mul_val">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;">= </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="form-control total">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How do i update total after making changes?

Hope you understand it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How can you change the computed value? the field after = is calculated from previous field. How and why will you edit that?

Comment: The problem is you're only every updating your `setTotalVal` input by adding the value that has changed to it. This means the values are just constantly added to this total number. You need to recalculate all of the equations every time a number is changed, and then set that result as the value in `setTotalVal`

Comment: That is where i got confused.Can you show me how to do?

Comment: So are you saying that field after `=` sign is editable? And when someone updates/changes value in that field, the total should get updated? Is that right?

Comment: yes, the total will get updated if you make some change in that box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code i get proper result I had made lot of changes at end hope you will get desired result:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mul_by').each(function (i) {
        var _this = $(this),
    //set default input value to zero inside .mul-by div
            setZero = _this.find('.form-control').val(0),
    //set default input value to zero inside .mul-val div
                setDenominationVal = _this.siblings('.mul_val').find('.form-control').val(0);

    //set default input value to zero inside .total div
        setTotalVal = $('.total').val(0);       
        setZero.on('change', function () {
    var getcurrentval = $(this).val();
    console.log('getcurrentval',getcurrentval)
    //watch and store input val. inside .mul_by
            var getUpdatedVal = _this.find('.form-control').val(),
      //get label text
                    getDenominationVal = parseInt(_this.siblings('label').text()),
      //update mul_by div after multiplication
                    updateDenominationVal = _this.siblings('.mul_val').find('.form-control');
                console.log(getUpdatedVal,getDenominationVal)
       var vals = 0,total=0;
            if(getUpdatedVal > 0){

       if(updateDenominationVal.val()>0){
            vals = updateDenominationVal.val(getUpdatedVal * getDenominationVal -   updateDenominationVal.val());

          total = parseInt(setTotalVal.val()) + parseInt(vals.val()) ;
          updateDenominationVal.val(getUpdatedVal * getDenominationVal);
          console.log('total',total,'setTotal',setTotalVal.val(),vals.val());
        }
        else{
            vals = updateDenominationVal.val(getUpdatedVal * getDenominationVal);
          updateDenominationVal.val(getUpdatedVal * getDenominationVal);
          total = parseInt(setTotalVal.val()) + parseInt(vals.val());
        }
        console.log(vals.val());


                setTotalVal.val(total);
            } else{
                updateDenominationVal.val(0);
            }
        });
    });
});
```